# Swift 4.2 - Returning classes created inside a function

Tags: swift

I wanted to declare a factory to help me create instances of singleton classes for testing, without the overhead of clearing the class-level state between test runs. My thought was to use a factory to return a class declared inside a function.

My assumption was that the class would be created on the fly, and would be retained only for as long as the returned reference was maintained. For example:

```
protocol TestClassFactory {
    static func make() -> TestClass.Type
}

protocol TestClass {
    static var testValue: String { get set }
}

class Factory: TestClassFactory {
    static func make() -> TestClass.Type {
        class Tester: TestClass {
            static var testValue = "Unmodified"
        }

        return Tester.self
    }
}
```

However, in practice, this didn't work as expected. Specifically, a static value set on the first `make()` return value persisted into the second.

```
var testClass1 = Factory.make()
print(testClass1.testValue)        // "Unmodified"
testClass1.testValue = "Modified"
print(testClass1.testValue)        // "Modified"

var testClass2 = Factory.make()
print(testClass2.testValue)        // "Modified"
```

The Swift runtime appeared to retain the class in its  just like a class declared and referenced at compile time.

My questions:

1. Does anyone have a reference that describes whether this behavior is intended? I'd assume it is but would like to know for sure.
2. For my particular use case, do I have any options other than using some kind of reflection/mirror to dynamically generate the type?

Comment: This is definitely intended. There are no types specific to one invocation. You cannot create new types at runtime in Swift. There are very few languages that actually allow such things.

Comment: By the way, if your singleton uses `static` variables, then you are doing it wrong. A singleton should be stored in a `static` variable but it should access only its instance variables. The whole concept does not make much sense. You should probably think how to refactor to make your code testable.

Comment: You can of course create new `@objc` types at runtime using the ObjC runtime. But agreed that this isn't possible for pure Swift types. I could see it being added as a continuation of the `@dynamic…` extensions in 4.2 and 5, since it would be another step towards Python bridging, which the Swift team wants. I don't think it'd ever look like the above code, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift is capable of creating new types at runtime, but I don't think that it's currently possible to use that capability as a language user.

In Swift, not all statements are executable: there is code that is evaluated at compile-time only and results in no executable code. Class statements are one of these. The class scope is not evaluated at runtime to create a new class: the compiler sees a class statement, builds that class, and gives you a static reference to that class going forward. That way, no code is executed at your program's startup (or at any other time, for that matter) when you create a class. This contrasts to other languages, such as Python, where every statement is inherently executable, and executing a class statement actually creates a class.

This behavior is emphasized by errors when you try to use local variables inside of function-local classes:

```
func foo(int: Int) {
    class Bar {
        let f = int
        // error: class declaration cannot close over value 'int' defined in outer
        // scope
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to allow creating new types at runtime or is it just functionality inherited from Objective-C?

Comment: @Sulthan, significant Objective-C programming concepts, such as key-value observing and Core Data, are built on creating new classes at runtime. I don't think that I have any Swift-specific use case to name, but they could become significant in some alternate timelines (for instance, if Swift gets non-type generic parameters).

Comment: I have never realized that KVO/Core Data works like that internally, interesting.

Comment: Oh yes. KVO invents new subclasses at runtime and swizzles existing instances to be that new class. Also, this would likely be helpful for bridging to Python, and for writing scripting languages inside of Swift.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation.